# Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ']' in C:\Programe\xampplite\xampplite\htdocs\insert.php on line 12

Tags: php

I'm having this error:

> Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ']' in C:\Programe\xampplite\xampplite\htdocs\insert.php on line 12

on this line:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tada (Nume, Prenume, Adresa, Tel, Anul, Nr.pantof) VALUES ('$_POST[Nume]','$_POST[Prenume]','$_POST[Adresa]','$_POST[Tel]','$_POST[Anul]','$_POST[Nr.pantof]')";
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

[image: xkcd]

Try this instead (assuming from your poor code quality that you're still using the old `mysql` extension):

```
$enc = "mysql_real_escape_string";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tada` (`Nume`, `Prenume`, `Adresa`, `Tel`, `Anul`, `Nr.pantof`)
        VALUES ('".$enc($_POST['Nume'])."', '".$enc($_POST['Prenume'])."',
        '".$enc($_POST['Adresa'])."', '".$enc($_POST['tel'])."',
        '".$enc($_POST['Anul'])."', '".$enc($_POST['Nr.pantof'])."')";
```

Also note that I added backticks `` ` `` around your column names. Otherwise MySQL would have attempted to access a table named `Nr` to find a column named `pantof` (or probably would have died on its own parse error).

In future, LEARN BASIC PRINCIPLES! There are literally MILLIONS of [search results for PHP/MySQL tutorials on Google](http://google.com/search?q=php+mysql+tutorial), use them!

Answer (score 2):

To embed array variables in string you should use this syntax:

```
"... {$array['key']} ..."
```

instead of:

```
 "... $array['key'] ..."
```

You should use curly brackets for everything else other then *normal* variables such as arrays:

```
{$a['key']}
```

or objects:

```
{$a->var}
```

Comment: `{$array[key]}` works too, however embedding variables is generally a bad idea anyway for readability reasons.